# How to lint YAML files, preferably in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

How do I lint YAML files, without having to upload it to http://yamllint.com ?

For example, if I have

```
people:
  1:
    :name: John Smith
    :name: Jane Smith
```

How do I make it warn me that the last `:name` over-writes the first `:name`?

I'm using Ruby 2.1, and Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [yamllint](http://yamllint.readthedocs.org/) command-line tool does what you
want:

```
sudo pip install yamllint
```

Specifically, it has a rule `key-duplicates` that detects repetitions and keys
over-writing one another:

```
$ yamllint test.yml
test.yml
  1:1       warning  missing document start "---"  (document-start)
  4:5       error    duplication of key ":name" in mapping  (key-duplicates)
```

(It has many other rules that you can enable/disable or tweak.)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

```
require 'yaml'

def check_yaml(filename)
  unless YAML.dump(YAML.load_file(filename)) == File.read(filename).gsub(/\s*#.*/, '')
    raise 'problem' 
  end
end

check_yaml 'somefile.yml'
```

Comment: You'd have to somehow strip away comments from the yaml file, as they'd definitely get lost in the process.

Comment: So long as there aren't any hash characters (`#`) within strings, it'd probably work.

Answer (score 0):

What about importing `1.yaml` and then exporting to `2.yaml`, and `diff 1.yaml 2.yaml`?
Can't supply the code -- no nix utils on this machine, but you've got the idea.